# Zend error Connection

Tags: json, postgresql, zend-framework

I have a problem with my code, the first code is like

```
<?php

    require_once('zend/json.php');
    require_once('zend/db.php');
    //require_once 'Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/pgsql.php';

    class jsonvi
    {
        protected $_db;
        public function _koneksi ()
        {
            try 
            {
                $this->_db = zend_db::factory('PDO_PGSQL',array( 
                'host'=>'localhost',
                'username'=>'stet',
                'password'=>'test',
                'dbname'=>'test'
            ));
                return $this->_db;                  
            }
            catch(zend_db_exception $e)
            {
                return $e->getmessage();
            }
    }
        public function getdata()
        {
            $db = $this->_koneksi();
            try
            {   


                $sql = "select * from info   ";
                $da = $db->fetchall($sql);
                $num = count($da);      
                for ($a=0;$a<$num;$a++)
                {
                    $data = $db->fetchall($sql);
                    return $data;
                }
            }
            catch (zend_db_exception $e)
            {
                return $e->getmessage();
            }
        }
    }
    $view = new jsonvi();
    $view = $view->getdata();
    echo zend_json::encode($view);

?>
```

and it works well, but I want to make it like

```
<?php

    include ('table.php');
    include ('config.php');
    require_once('zend/json.php');
    require_once('zend/db.php');
    require_once 'Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/pgsql.php';

    class jsonvi
    {
        protected $_db;
        public function _koneksi ()
        {
            try 
            {
                $this->_db = zend_db::factory('PDO_PGSQL',array( 
                'host'=>$dbhost,
                'username'=>$dbuser,
                'password'=>$dbpass,
                'dbname'=>$dbdb
            ));
                return $this->_db;                  
            }
            catch(zend_db_exception $e)
            {
                return $e->getmessage();
            }
    }
        public function getdata()
        {
            $db = $this->_koneksi();
            try
            {   


                $sql = "select * from ".$table;
                $da = $db->fetchall($sql);
                $num = count($da);      
                for ($a=0;$a<$num;$a++)
                {
                    $data = $db->fetchall($sql);
                    return $data;
                }
            }
            catch (zend_db_exception $e)
            {
                return $e->getmessage();
            }
        }
    }
    $view = new jsonvi();
    $view = $view->getdata();
    echo zend_json::encode($view);      
?>
```

I don't know whats wrong with this code, I need help.
the error message `Notice: Undefined variable: dbdb in C:\wamp....`
The config.php is only have code like `$dbpass = 'test';` and like that, I'm creating a simple web and I want to make my code to other database and aplikasi, so I only changed the `config.php` and the `table.php`
for the table.php maybe will work if the `config.php` work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a class and not paying attention to variable scope.

I understand you have variables with values for the DB connection in that `config.php` file. Although these variables are available inside the script file with the include they are NOT available and accessible inside your class. The only difference would be any constants with define (or variables inside a global which is not a good idea).

You could create a config class inside the config.php and set the values as properties then instantiate that class inside your `_koneksi` method. And then you would use a require_once instead of the include.

**UPDATE**
So here's an example that is similar to your file where your `include ('config.php');` is essentially the same as declaring your variables directly before the class begins.

```
// variable defined outside the class
$foo = 'foo';

class demo
{
    public $bar = 'bar';

    function test()
    {
        $foobar = 'foobar';
        echo 'Class property $bar is:' . $this->bar . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Local variable $foobar is:' . $foobar . PHP_EOL;
    }

    function run() 
    {
        if (isset($foo)) {
            echo 'Global variable $foo is:' . $foo . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            // This is where you have your problem.
            // Variables from outside the class are not available.
            echo 'Global variable $foo not found' . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

$demo = new demo();
$demo->test();       // Class property $bar is:bar
                     // Local variable $foobar is:foobar

$demo->run();        // Global variable $foo not found

echo 'Variable $foo is: ' . $foo . PHP_EOL;  // Class property $bar is:bar
```

Comment: See my update. I hope that helps understanding the problem.

Comment: thanks bro after the long search, i finaly made it, (or found it hha)
i almost same with the update. thanks again.